# node/express: set NODE_ENV when using Forever to run script continuously

Tags: node.js, express

How can I set the [NODE_ENV](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration) variable/parameter to "production" when I'm using [forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever) to start my node script

I got this so far:

```
forever start -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log -a app.js
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can set NODE_ENV as normal and then run forever:

```
NODE_ENV=production forever [flags] start app.js [app_flags]
```

The initial `NODE_ENV` will be preserved when the server restarts - behaviour that was fixed in this issue:

https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/116

Older versions of forever can use the following command line format:

```
NODE_ENV=production forever [flags] app.js
```

Comment: but how do i set it "as normal"?

Comment: I could have been more specific and said, "without forever" instead of "as normal".

But:

NODE_ENV=production forever app.js

Comment: This issue has been fixed to work on restarts: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/search?q=116.

Comment: Don't know if this help, and you might have meant this with [Flags] but NODE_ENV=production forever start app.js is how I got it to work.  Without it, it doesn't actually do the forever part.

Comment: @binarygiant That appears to be an update to forever's API. I'll update the original answer with the new information.