# Why is this not working? Testing non exported-function with Rewire / Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Pretty much running the exact same code elsewhere however, this time, I am using rewire to test a non-exported function at  **helper.js**.

When debugging the following I get to **return await db.collection('foo')** which **returns undefined** and **throwing** when attempting **'undefined.findOne()'** naturally. My understanding is that **db.collection('foo')** **should** **return** **mockDbConnect** in this case allowing to chain **findOne**, which it is not doing...

Help is appreciated.

**foo.test.js**

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const helper = rewire('../../../src/models/helper/helpers');

describe('model helpers', () => {
    describe('searchValue', () => {
        it('should return an instance', async () => {
            const searchValue = helper.__get__('searchValue')
            const mockFoo = { foo: '1' }
            const fooId = '1';
            const mockDbConnect = {
                collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                findOne: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockFoo)
            }
            try {
                const res = await searchValue(fooId, mockDbConnect);
                expect(mockDbConnect.collection).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foos');
            } catch (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    })
})
```

**helpers.js**

```js
const searchValue = async (fooId, db) => {
    return await db
        .collection('foos')
        .findOne({ fooId: fooId });
};
```

Comment: Origin of this? `mockPortfolioId` - doesn't exist in your source

Comment: Edited, mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unit test a method which connects to mongo, without actually connecting to mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585569/how-to-unit-test-a-method-which-connects-to-mongo-without-actually-connecting-t)

Comment: Can't reproduce it. It works fine.